# RequestThrottled For Amazon Associates

Tags: affiliate

It looks like my amazon associates account may be banned.  No matter how long I wait, I get a 503 error saying 'You are submitting requests too quickly. Please retry your requests at a slower rate.'.

I'm only using this API to get the Title and Image from ASINs.

Is there a better method to get this information?  It appears the associates api may be banning me because I haven't had any ad revenue associated with my account.

Comment: Are you by any chance using the http protocol?

Comment: I sure was.  However, after changing it, I still get the same error

Comment: Gotcha - I am getting throttled this morning as well, starting at 6 AM Pacific.

Comment: If your account doesn't generate sales in the 30 days you will loose API access https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/prod-adv-api-dg.pdf page 158.
And to regain access you have to sell...
Completely stupid...

Comment: Did you find a way around this? I am happy to pay for access to the Product Advertsing API but it would appear you _have_ to have an Affiliate Account that is actively driving sales to Amazon?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information was easy enough to come by with just scraping the page and there's no throttling.

I'm now using xpath:

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();

    @$doc->loadHTMLFile('https://amazon.com/dp/' . $_GET['asin']);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $title = $xpath->evaluate('//*[@id="productTitle"]');
    $title = trim($title[0]->nodeValue);

    $image = $xpath->evaluate('//*[@id="landingImage"]');
    $image = trim($image[0]->getAttribute('src'));

    $buybox = $xpath->evaluate('//*[@id="price_inside_buybox"]');
    $buybox = trim($buybox[0]->nodeValue);

    die(json_encode([
      'asin'        => $_GET['asin'],
      'title'       => $title,
      'buybox'      => str_replace('$', '', $buybox),
      'image'       => "<img src=\"" . $image . "\" />",
    ]));
```